# EF Migration : Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype (COLUMN) is wrong

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I'm trying to update my database with a migration.
I probably messed up when I deleted by hand all my tables and then recreated by hand.

I'm using code first, and the Add-Migration command gave me this :

```
 public override void Up()
        {
        DropForeignKey("[dbo.Products]", "[Bundle_Id]", "[dbo.Bundles]");
        DropForeignKey("[dbo.Defects]", "[Product_Id]", "[dbo.Products]");
        DropForeignKey("[dbo.Defects]", "[User_Id]", "[dbo.Users]");
        RenameColumn(table: "[dbo.Products]", name: "[Bundle_Id]", newName: "[Bundles_BundlesId]");
        RenameColumn(table: "[dbo.Defects]", name: "[Product_Id]", newName: "[Products_ProductsId]");
        RenameColumn(table: "[dbo.Defects]", name: "[User_Id]", newName: "[Users_UsersId]");
        RenameIndex(table: "[dbo.Products]", name: "[IX_Bundle_Id]", newName: "[IX_Bundles_BundlesId]");
        RenameIndex(table: "[dbo.Defects]", name: "[IX_Product_Id]", newName: "[IX_Products_ProductsId]");
        RenameIndex(table: "[dbo.Defects]", name: "[IX_User_Id]", newName: "[IX_Users_UsersId]");
        DropPrimaryKey("[dbo.Bundles]");
        DropPrimaryKey("[dbo.Defects]");
        DropPrimaryKey("[dbo.Products]");
        DropPrimaryKey("[dbo.Users]");
        AddColumn("[dbo.Bundles]", "[BundlesId]", c => c.Long(nullable: false, identity: true));
        AddColumn("[dbo.Defects]", "[DefectsId]", c => c.Long(nullable: false, identity: true));
        AddColumn("[dbo.Defects]", "[ProductsId]", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
        AddColumn("[dbo.Defects]", "[UsersId]", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
        AddColumn("[dbo.Products]", "[ProductsId]", c => c.Long(nullable: false, identity: true));
        AddColumn("[dbo.Products]", "[BundlesId]", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
        AddColumn("[dbo.Users]", "[UsersId]", c => c.Long(nullable: false, identity: true));
        AddPrimaryKey("[dbo.Bundles]", "[BundlesId]");
        AddPrimaryKey("[dbo.Defects]", "[DefectsId]");
        AddPrimaryKey("[dbo.Products]", "[ProductsId]");
        AddPrimaryKey("[dbo.Users]", "[UsersId]");
        AddForeignKey("[dbo.Products]", "[Bundles_BundlesId]", "[dbo.Bundles]", "[BundlesId]");
        AddForeignKey("[dbo.Defects]", "[Products_ProductsId]", "[dbo.Products]", "[ProductsId]");
        AddForeignKey("[dbo.Defects]", "[Users_UsersId]", "[dbo.Users]", "[UsersId]");
        DropColumn("[dbo.Bundles]", "[Id]");
        DropColumn("[dbo.Defects]", "[Id]");
        DropColumn("[dbo.Defects]", "[ProductId]");
        DropColumn("[dbo.Defects]", "[UserId]");
        DropColumn("[dbo.Products]", "[Id]");
        DropColumn("[dbo.Products]", "[BundleId]");
        DropColumn("[dbo.Users]", "[Id]");
        }

    public override void Down()
        {
        AddColumn("[dbo.Users]", "[Id]", c => c.Long(nullable: false, identity: true));
        AddColumn("[dbo.Products]", "[BundleId]", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
        AddColumn("[dbo.Products]", "[Id]", c => c.Long(nullable: false, identity: true));
        AddColumn("[dbo.Defects]", "[UserId]", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
        AddColumn("[dbo.Defects]", "[ProductId]", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
        AddColumn("[dbo.Defects]", "[Id]", c => c.Long(nullable: false, identity: true));
        AddColumn("[dbo.Bundles]", "[Id]", c => c.Long(nullable: false, identity: true));
        DropForeignKey("[dbo.Defects]", "[Users_UsersId]", "[dbo.Users]");
        DropForeignKey("[dbo.Defects]", "[Products_ProductsId]", "[dbo.Products]");
        DropForeignKey("[dbo.Products]", "[Bundles_BundlesId]", "[dbo.Bundles]");
        DropPrimaryKey("[dbo.Users]");
        DropPrimaryKey("[dbo.Products]");
        DropPrimaryKey("[dbo.Defects]");
        DropPrimaryKey("[dbo.Bundles]");
        DropColumn("[dbo.Users]", "[UsersId]");
        DropColumn("[dbo.Products]", "[BundlesId]");
        DropColumn("[dbo.Products]", "[ProductsId]");
        DropColumn("[dbo.Defects]", "[UsersId]");
        DropColumn("[dbo.Defects]", "[ProductsId]");
        DropColumn("[dbo.Defects]", "[DefectsId]");
        DropColumn("[dbo.Bundles]", "[BundlesId]");
        AddPrimaryKey("[dbo.Users]", "[Id]");
        AddPrimaryKey("[dbo.Products]", "[Id]");
        AddPrimaryKey("[dbo.Defects]", "[Id]");
        AddPrimaryKey("[dbo.Bundles]", "[Id]");
        RenameIndex(table: "[dbo.Defects]", name: "[IX_Users_UsersId]", newName: "[IX_User_Id]");
        RenameIndex(table: "[dbo.Defects]", name: "[IX_Products_ProductsId]", newName: "[IX_Product_Id]");
        RenameIndex(table: "[dbo.Products]", name: "[IX_Bundles_BundlesId]", newName: "[IX_Bundle_Id]");
        RenameColumn(table: "[dbo.Defects]", name: "[Users]_UsersId]", newName: "[User_Id]");
        RenameColumn(table: "[dbo.Defects]", name: "[Products_ProductsId]", newName: "[Product_Id]");
        RenameColumn(table: "[dbo.Products]", name: "[Bundles_BundlesId]", newName: "[Bundle_Id]");
        AddForeignKey("[dbo.Defects]", "[User_Id]", "[dbo.Users]", "[Id]");
        AddForeignKey("[dbo.Defects]", "[Product_Id]", "[dbo.Products]", "[Id]");
        AddForeignKey("[dbo.Products]", "[Bundle_Id]", "[dbo.Bundles]", "[Id]");
        }
```

I surrounded every name with the brackets ('[' and ']') which apparently helped some people in my case.
I'm posting because, you guessed it, it did not for me.

I'm always getting the :

> Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype (COLUMN) is wrong.

Would anyone have a guess about what is forbidding me from updating my database ? Should I start fresh from another project ?

Thanks !

EDIT : After comment poiting my brackets were placed in the wrong way, I updated to :

```
public partial class Migr : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        DropForeignKey("[dbo].[Products]", "[Bundle_Id]", "[dbo].[Bundles]");
        DropForeignKey("[dbo].[Defects]", "[Product_Id]", "[dbo].[Products]");
        DropForeignKey("[dbo].[Defects]", "[User_Id]", "[dbo].[Users]");
        RenameColumn(table: "[dbo].[Products]", name: "[Bundle_Id]", newName: "[Bundles_BundlesId]");
        RenameColumn(table: "[dbo].[Defects]", name: "[Product_Id]", newName: "[Products_ProductsId]");
        RenameColumn(table: "[dbo].[Defects]", name: "[User_Id]", newName: "[Users_UsersId]");
        RenameIndex(table: "[dbo].[Products]", name: "[IX_Bundle_Id]", newName: "[IX_Bundles_BundlesId]");
        RenameIndex(table: "[dbo].[Defects]", name: "[IX_Product_Id]", newName: "[IX_Products_ProductsId]");
        RenameIndex(table: "[dbo].[Defects]", name: "[IX_User_Id]", newName: "[IX_Users_UsersId]");
        DropPrimaryKey("[dbo].[Bundles]");
        DropPrimaryKey("[dbo].[Defects]");
        DropPrimaryKey("[dbo].[Products]");
        DropPrimaryKey("[dbo].[Users]");
        AddColumn("[dbo].[Bundles]", "[BundlesId]", c => c.Long(nullable: false, identity: true));
        AddColumn("[dbo].[Defects]", "[DefectsId]", c => c.Long(nullable: false, identity: true));
        AddColumn("[dbo].[Defects]", "[ProductsId]", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
        AddColumn("[dbo].[Defects]", "[UsersId]", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
        AddColumn("[dbo].[Products]", "[ProductsId]", c => c.Long(nullable: false, identity: true));
        AddColumn("[dbo].[Products]", "[BundlesId]", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
        AddColumn("[dbo].[Users]", "[UsersId]", c => c.Long(nullable: false, identity: true));
        AddPrimaryKey("[dbo].[Bundles]", "[BundlesId]");
        AddPrimaryKey("[dbo].[Defects]", "[DefectsId]");
        AddPrimaryKey("[dbo].[Products]", "[ProductsId]");
        AddPrimaryKey("[dbo].[Users]", "[UsersId]");
        AddForeignKey("[dbo].[Products]", "[Bundles_BundlesId]", "[dbo].[Bundles]", "[BundlesId]");
        AddForeignKey("[dbo].[Defects]", "[Products_ProductsId]", "[dbo].[Products]", "[ProductsId]");
        AddForeignKey("[dbo].[Defects]", "[Users_UsersId]", "[dbo].[Users]", "[UsersId]");
        DropColumn("[dbo].[Bundles]", "[Id]");
        DropColumn("[dbo].[Defects]", "[Id]");
        DropColumn("[dbo].[Defects]", "[ProductId]");
        DropColumn("[dbo].[Defects]", "[UserId]");
        DropColumn("[dbo].[Products]", "[Id]");
        DropColumn("[dbo].[Products]", "[BundleId]");
        DropColumn("[dbo].[Users]", "[Id]");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        AddColumn("[dbo].[Users]", "[Id]", c => c.Long(nullable: false, identity: true));
        AddColumn("[dbo].[Products]", "[BundleId]", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
        AddColumn("[dbo].[Products]", "[Id]", c => c.Long(nullable: false, identity: true));
        AddColumn("[dbo].[Defects]", "[UserId]", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
        AddColumn("[dbo].[Defects]", "[ProductId]", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
        AddColumn("[dbo].[Defects]", "[Id]", c => c.Long(nullable: false, identity: true));
        AddColumn("[dbo].[Bundles]", "[Id]", c => c.Long(nullable: false, identity: true));
        DropForeignKey("[dbo].[Defects]", "[Users_UsersId]", "[dbo].[Users]");
        DropForeignKey("[dbo].[Defects]", "[Products_ProductsId]", "[dbo].[Products]");
        DropForeignKey("[dbo].[Products]", "[Bundles_BundlesId]", "[dbo].[Bundles]");
        DropPrimaryKey("[dbo].[Users]");
        DropPrimaryKey("[dbo].[Products]");
        DropPrimaryKey("[dbo].[Defects]");
        DropPrimaryKey("[dbo].[Bundles]");
        DropColumn("[dbo].[Users]", "[UsersId]");
        DropColumn("[dbo].[Products]", "[BundlesId]");
        DropColumn("[dbo].[Products]", "[ProductsId]");
        DropColumn("[dbo].[Defects]", "[UsersId]");
        DropColumn("[dbo].[Defects]", "[ProductsId]");
        DropColumn("[dbo].[Defects]", "[DefectsId]");
        DropColumn("[dbo].[Bundles]", "[BundlesId]");
        AddPrimaryKey("[dbo].[Users]", "[Id]");
        AddPrimaryKey("[dbo].[Products]", "[Id]");
        AddPrimaryKey("[dbo].[Defects]", "[Id]");
        AddPrimaryKey("[dbo].[Bundles]", "[Id]");
        RenameIndex(table: "[dbo].[Defects]", name: "[IX_Users_UsersId]", newName: "[IX_User_Id]");
        RenameIndex(table: "[dbo].[Defects]", name: "[IX_Products_ProductsId]", newName: "[IX_Product_Id]");
        RenameIndex(table: "[dbo].[Products]", name: "[IX_Bundles_BundlesId]", newName: "[IX_Bundle_Id]");
        RenameColumn(table: "[dbo].[Defects]", name: "[Users]_UsersId]", newName: "[User_Id]");
        RenameColumn(table: "[dbo].[Defects]", name: "[Products_ProductsId]", newName: "[Product_Id]");
        RenameColumn(table: "[dbo].[Products]", name: "[Bundles_BundlesId]", newName: "[Bundle_Id]");
        AddForeignKey("[dbo].[Defects]", "[User_Id]", "[dbo].[Users]", "[Id]");
        AddForeignKey("[dbo].[Defects]", "[Product_Id]", "[dbo].[Products]", "[Id]");
        AddForeignKey("[dbo].[Products]", "[Bundle_Id]", "[dbo].[Bundles]", "[Id]");
    }
}
```

Which does not solve my problem unfortunately.

Comment: Your brackets are wrong. For example `[dbo.Users]` should really be `[dbo].[Users]`

Comment: Oh, that makes sense, I'll try that. Thanks !

Comment: No luck, did not change my issue. Thank you for trying.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? If you just want to rebuild your database based on your code first model you don't need migrations - you can do that with an Initializer like DropCreate... If you need to synchronize a deployed database there are different techniques for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was that for some reason, when I ran `Create-Migration`, it generated a command referencing a field in a table that didn't exist. Once I fixed that, it ran perfectly.